# Auto change Woocommerce Subscriptions status to "On-Hold" rather than "Active"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-subscriptions

In Woocommerce, I would like to automatically put all Woocommerce Subscriptions "on hold" rather than "active" when the order is still "processing". Once I mark the order as "completed" that subscription should change to "active".

I've tried everything I can think of, if somebody knows how to do this please let me know.

I'm running wordpress 4.8.1 / Woocommerce 3.1.2 / Woocommerce Subscriptions 2.2.7 / and the payment gateway is Stripe 3.2.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done in two steps:

1) With a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_thankyou`** action hook, when the order has a 'processing' status and contains subscriptions, we **update** the subscriptions status to **'on-hold'**:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_thankyou_subscription_action', 50, 1 );
function custom_thankyou_subscription_action( $order_id ){
    if( ! $order_id ) return;

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // Get an instance of the WC_Order object

    // If the order has a 'processing' status and contains a subscription 
    if( wcs_order_contains_subscription( $order ) && $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ){

        // Get an array of WC_Subscription objects
        $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order( $order_id );
        foreach( $subscriptions as $subscription_id => $subscription ){
            // Change the status of the WC_Subscription object
            $subscription->update_status( 'on-hold' );
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

2) With a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_order_status_completed`** action hook, when the order status is changed to "completed", it will **auto change** the subscription status to **"active"**:

```
// When Order is "completed" auto-change the status of the WC_Subscription object to 'on-hold'
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed','updating_order_status_completed_with_subscription');
function updating_order_status_completed_with_subscription($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);  // Get an instance of the WC_Order object

    if( wcs_order_contains_subscription( $order ) ){

        // Get an array of WC_Subscription objects
        $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order( $order_id );
        foreach( $subscriptions as $subscription_id => $subscription ){
            // Change the status of the WC_Subscription object
            $subscription->update_status( 'active' );
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

All code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.